# Call vert.x web API from another vert.x Web API

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-eventbus, vert.x-webclient

I have one vert.x WEB API exposed at localhost:8080/api/search?id=123 and relative method in java is this

```
@Override
  public void searchUser(ServiceRequest serviceRequest, Handler<AsyncResult<ServiceResponse>> eventHandler) {
// Logic 
}
```

I want to call the above method from another vert.x api I tried using eventBus().request but some how I am not able to pass query parameter. Method is mentioned below from where I need to call above method.

```
@Override
public void postUserFuture(JsonObject body, ServiceRequest serviceRequest,
            Handler<AsyncResult<ServiceResponse>> eventHandler) {
}
```

Anyone with vert.x experience please help me to resolve this. TIA